# How do I apply or run a thinkscript in thinkorswim

Tags: thinkscript

How do I run or apply a script in thinkorswim? I found some sample scripts and looked at a number of videos, however no one is showing how to run the scripts against a stock once you have it, they just stop short of that. I code but I'm new to thinkorswim.

I tried the documentation and several tutorials.

Comment: Did you look at the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/thinkscript/info)?